# Are my Environment settings being wiped out on launch?

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-neon

Each time I restart my machine and launch the IDE, I lose all my installed packages (eg. Gradle build ship, EclEmma, SonarQube etc.) and I am force to reinstall them over and over again.

After I install them, it asks me to restart the IDE, which it does, and it doesn't lose the plugins at that point.  But on a full restart, it somehow loses it.

This happened even with different versions on Neon (4.6.1, 4.6.3).

I reuse the same workspace folder, and it don't see any weird permission problems.

Ideas?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with an actual version of Eclipse (Oxygen.1a alias 4.7.1a)? Will your home directory be reverted or overwritten by some tool?

Comment: I'm actually using Neon 4.6.3.  Nothing appears to change.

Comment: Try to reproduce it with [Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a)](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/) because of [this](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7/platform.php#eclipse-as-signed-dmg) and because Eclipse Neon is no longer maintained.